# Solving differential equation featuring $f(1)$ as a coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

Starting with $g(x)=\int_{1/x}^1 g(kx)(2-2k)dk+1,$ after integration by parts of the RHS I get the following DE for the second antiderivative of $g(x),$ say $f(x)$:

$x^2f''(x)+(2x-2)f'(1)-2(f(x)-f(1))-1=0.$

I'm not really sure how to approach this - for instance, if I pretend $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ are merely constants, I can spot the differential operator

$x^2f''(x)-2f(x)$

has eigenfunctions $1/x$ and $x^2$. However, the usual plan of using these homogeneous solutions to find the general solution seems not to work, as my homogeneous solutions (and their first derivatives) don't vanish at $x=1$.

Is there perhaps a better way of attacking the original integral equation? It's also worth mentioning I have a BC - namely $g(1)=1.$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2f''(x)+(2x-2)f'(1)-2(f(x)-f(1))-1=0.$$
$$x^2f''(x)-2f(x)=Ax+B$$
$$x^2f''(x)\color{red}{+2xf'-2xf'}-2f(x)=Ax+B$$
$$(x^2f'(x))'-2(xf(x))'=Ax+B$$
$$(x^2f'(x)-2xf(x))'=Ax+B$$
Integrate both sides to reduce the order of the DE. Or you can rexrite the DE as:
$$\left ( x^4 \left(\dfrac {f(x)}{x^2}\right)'\right)'= Ax + B$$
Integrate twice.

Comment: Using your first suggestion,
$$(x^2f'(x)-2xf(x))'=Ax+B,$$
so $$x^2f'(x)-2xf(x)=\frac{A}{2}x^2+Bx+C$$. Dividing both sides by $x^4$,
$$(\frac{f(x)}{x^2})'=\frac{A}{2}x^{-2}+Bx^{-3}+Cx^{-4}$$
so $$\frac{f}{x^2}=-\frac{A}{2}x^{-1}-\frac{B}{2}x^{-2}-\frac{C}{3}x^{-3}$$
so $$f=-\frac{Ax}{2}-\frac{B}{2}-\frac{C}{3x}.$$
At this point we recall we defined $A=-2f'(1), B=2f'(1)-2f(1)+1.$ Subbing in $x=1$ into $f(x)$ above and that expression's derivative, and noting $g(1)=f''(1)=1$, we get a system of three equations for the three unknowns $A,B,C$, which turns out to have no solution.

Comment: I think the reason this happens is precisely because we can't assume $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ are constants for the purposes of the DE - I'm not really sure though.

Comment: I just tried to solve the differential equation you posted ...I guess that you're right in the second comment£ @Zerkoff

Comment: You forgot a constant of integration in your calculations since it's a second order DE you should have two constants of integration...$C_1$ and $C_2$ .@Zerkoff

Comment: Right you are, but even still it seems to have no solution.